# Find first day of last week of year with java.time

Tags: java, date, java-time

I need to find the first day of the last week of a year using Java 8 Date and Time API ([java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)) and finally came to this solution:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2016, 2, 17);
LocalDate lastWeekOfYear = LocalDate.of(date.getYear() + 1, 1, 7)
    .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfYear(), 1)
    .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)).minusDays(7);
```

This solution finds the first week of the next year, adjusts the day of week to Monday if necessary and moves 7 days back. Is there a smarter way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Looks okay to me, although I'd probably use `minusWeeks(1)` instead of `minusDays(7)`, and put it on a new line. You could potentially write your own `TemporalAdjuster` for `lastWeekOfWeekYear`

Comment: An alternative (not necessarily more readable) would be `date.with(lastDayOfYear()).minusDays(7 - WeekFields.ISO.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()).with(previousOrSame(MONDAY))`

Comment: @Oxolotl I suggest you extract your proposed solution, and post it as an Answer. You can later accept it to flag the Question as closed. Perfectly okay to answer your own Question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Using my lib Time4J enables a [more elegant solution](https://gist.github.com/MenoData/5491d35aa2c046fca27b5d298ebf5750). The adjustment code would reduce to `date = date.with(ISO.weekOfYear().maximized()).with(DAY_OF_WEEK, MONDAY);` Otherwise - when only using java.time-package - I strongly recommend to use [weekOfWeekBasedYear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekOfWeekBasedYear--) - see also the subtile diff to `weekOfYear()` in java.time-API.

Comment: Thanks @MenoHochschild for suggesting using `weekOfWeekBasedYear()`, I updated the solution accordingly. But as I asked for a plain java.time solution, usage of another library ist out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested, I'll answer the question myself (with a minor enhancement from the comments) as there does not seem to be a significantly simpler solution.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2016, 2, 17);
LocalDate lastWeekOfYear = LocalDate.of(date.getYear() + 1, 1, 7)
    .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 1)
    .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)).minusWeeks(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

UPDATED based on your comment:

You can start from your date, get the last day of the year and go back till Mondays. Get the WeekBasedYear of this result and accept it if the weekBasedYear is the same as the day year, otherways go back to the previous Monday and accept it as result:

```
LocalDate day = LocalDate.of(2012, 2, 17);
LocalDate result =  day.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear())
                            .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));      

//if day and result weekBasedYear are in the same weekYear then result else go back to previous Mondays
result = result.get(WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear())== day.getYear()? result :
                result.with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));

System.out.println(result);
```

output:

```
2012-12-24
```

hope this can help.

Comment: I think this solution does return wrong results for the case that the last day of the year is a Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday. For example, in 2012 the last week of year starts at 2012-12-24, while the code above would return 2012-12-31. I should have pointed out in my question that I require the last week according to ISO 8601 week (see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates]).

Comment: @Oxolotl Yes, you certainly should have defined your terms, in this case what you mean by week-of-year. Please edit your Question with such clarifications rather than post as comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think the last solution found by OP is still not correct because **we are moving in the context of ISO-week-dates, not ordinary calendar dates**. So the expression `LocalDate.of(date.getYear() + 1, 1, 7)` will often be wrong around the year boundary (see the example method `lastWeekOfYearOld(...)`). Instead we have to add a week-based-year, not a calendar year (bound to January-December) which has now been used in the second method `lastWeekOfYearCorrect(...)`. I also show another correct alternative based on the context-sensitive value range of the week-of-year-field (see method `lastWeekOfYearAlternative(...)`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
              lastWeekOfYearOld(LocalDate.of(2015, 12, 31))); // 2015-12-28 (OK)
    System.out.println(
              lastWeekOfYearOld(LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 1))); // 2016-12-26 (Wrong)

    System.out.println(
              lastWeekOfYearCorrect(LocalDate.of(2015, 12, 31))); // 2015-12-28 (OK)
    System.out.println(
              lastWeekOfYearCorrect(LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 1))); // 2015-12-28 (OK)

    System.out.println(
              lastWeekOfYearAlternative(LocalDate.of(2015, 12, 31))); // 2015-12-28 (OK)
    System.out.println(
              lastWeekOfYearAlternative(LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 1))); // 2015-12-28 (OK)
}

private static LocalDate lastWeekOfYearOld(LocalDate date) {
    return LocalDate.of(date.getYear() + 1, 1, 7)
         .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 1)
         .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)).minusWeeks(1);
}

private static LocalDate lastWeekOfYearCorrect(LocalDate date) {
    date =
      date.plus(1, IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEARS)
          .with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
          .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 1);
    return date.minusWeeks(1);
}

private static LocalDate lastWeekOfYearAlternative(LocalDate date) {
    TemporalField woyField = WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear();
    date = date.with(woyField, woyField.rangeRefinedBy(date).getMaximum());
    return date.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
}
```

Comment: The above solution does not work as expected for me, but I understand your point and think my question may still be ambigous. I was looking for a solution to the question "What is the last week of 2016?" - the day and month components of the passed `LocalDate` is therefore irrelevant. It would be clearer if I had asked for an implementation of a method with the signature `LocalDate lastWeekOfYear(int year)`.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
org.threeten.extra.YearWeek.from(  // Represents an entire week at a time, using standard ISO 8601 definition of “week”. 
    LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.FEBRUARY , 17 )
)                                  // Returns a `YearWeek` object to represent the week containing that date. 
.plusYears( 1 )                    // Move to following year.
.withWeek( 1 )                     // Move to the first week of that following year.
.minusWeeks( 1 )                   // Move to the prior week, which would be the last week of our desired week-based-year.
.atDay(                            // Determine the date of a particular day-of-week within that week.
    DayOfWeek.MONDAY               // Use the handy `java.time.DayOfWeek` enum predefining seven objects, one for each day of the week.
)                                  // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.toString()                        // Generate a String representing this `LocalDate` value in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2016-12-26

## `YearWeek`

The [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library provides additional date-time classes that complement those in *java.time*.

The [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class from that library suits your purpose. This class represents the entire week of a week-based year using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) definition.

Get the current year-week.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ;  // Get the current year-week as seen in the wall-clock time of people inhabiting a particular region (a time zone).
```

Or get the `YearWeek` for a particular date.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.FEBRUARY , 17 ) ;  // Feb 2, 2016.
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.from( ld ) ;
```

Determine the last week number of this year, either 52 or 53. Here we use a ternary operator instead of a longer `if-else` statement.

```
int w = yw.is53WeekYear​() ? 53 : 52 ;  // Determine last week number, either 52 or 53.
```

Move to that last week of this week-based-year.

```
YearWeek ywLastOfYear = yw.withWeek( w ) ; // Produce a new `YearWeek` object based on the original’s values but for some adjustment - here we use the same year but use a different week number.
```

Finally, get the date of the first day of that week, where the first day is Monday.

```
LocalDate firstDayOfLastYearWeek = ywLastOfYear.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
```

That is one approach. See the *tl;dr* section above for another approach.